# R Script - TopGO Package

Tags: r

I am an R beginner. I am using the `{TopGO}` R Package for performing enrichment analysis for gene ontology.

In the last part of the script (#create topGO object), I get this error:

```
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : allGenes must be a factor with 2 levels
```

Could you please help me with this? I really appreciate your help. Thanks

Below I have reported the R script I have used. I would like to upload also my starting dataset but I don't know how to to it.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
# if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
#  install.packages("BiocManager")
# BiocManager::install("topGO")
library(topGO)

# make table from meta data holding grouping information for each sample
# in this case landrace, cultivar ...
getwd()         
setwd("C:/Users/iaia-/Desktop/")
background <- fread('anno.variable.out.txt') %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  #the ID is the actual GO term
  mutate(id = as.numeric(id)) %>% 
  na.omit() %>%
  
  #according to pannzer2 ARGOT is the best scoring algorithm
  filter(str_detect(type ,'ARGOT'),
         #choose a PPV value
         #according to the pannzer2 manual, there is no 'best' option
         # Philipp advised to use 0.4, 0.6, 0.8
         # maybe I write a loop to check differences later
         PPV >=0.6 ) %>% 
  #create a ontology  column to have the 3 ontology options, which topGO supports
  # 'BP' - biological process, 'MF' - molecular function, 'CC' - cellular component
  mutate(ontology=sapply(strsplit(type,'_'),'[',1)) %>% 
  #select the 3 columns we need
  dplyr::select(id,ontology, qpid) %>% 
  #add GO: to the GO ids
  dplyr::mutate(id=paste0('GO:',id))

foreground <- fread('LIST.txt',header=F)
colnames(foreground) <- c("rowname")
#rename type to group to prevent confusion
#dplyr::rename(group=type)

#for all groups together
all_results <- tibble()
for (o in unique(background$ontology)){
  #filter background for a certain ontology
  ont_background <- filter(background, ontology==o)} #BIOLOGICAL PROCESS

annAT <- split(ont_background$qpid,ont_background$id)
#filter foreground for a group
fg_genes <- foreground %>%  pull(rowname)


ont_background <- ont_background %>% 
  mutate(present=as.factor(ifelse(qpid %in% fg_genes,1,0))) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-id) %>% distinct() %>%  
  pull(present, name = qpid)

#create topGO object
GOdata <-new("topGOdata", ontology = o, allGenes = ont_background, nodeSize = 5,annot=annFUN.GO2genes,GO2genes=annAT)
weight01.fisher <- runTest(GOdata, statistic = "fisher")
results <- GenTable(GOdata, classicFisher=weight01.fisher,topNodes=ifelse(length(GOdata@graph@nodes) < 30,length(GOdata@graph@nodes),30)) %>% 
  dplyr::rename(pvalue=6) %>% 
  mutate(ontology=o,
         pvalue=as.numeric(pvalue))
all_results <- bind_rows(all_results,results)
}

#all_results %>% pull(GO.ID) %>% writeClipboard()
resultspvalue<- all_results %>% dplyr::select(GO.ID,pvalue)
write_tsv(resultspvalue, "GOTermsrep_pvalue.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to say for sure without knowing what ont_background looked like before you modified it, but based on [these](https://www.biostars.org/p/273219/) [threads](https://www.biostars.org/p/273171/) I think that there's a problem with the final ont_background object you are using to make the topGO object in your final "#create topGO object" chunk.

It looks like the allGenes argument (ont_background) needs to be a vector of pvalues with names() assigned as the gene names in whatever format you are using for other arguments.